# Is the transformation matrix for a proper subspace W of vector space V inveritable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume ***W*** is a  proper subspace of vector space ***V***.

$$dim V> dim W$$

Assume {$\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3...,\beta_n$} be the set of ordered basis of W.
$$dim V>n$$

Assume **P** be the matrix that transform one coordinate system to another. (I don't know the name of the matrix. It is the matrix that come in the change of basis.)

Now the column space of P is this basis set. But sometimes this matrix is not square.

Take the case where $\Bbb C^3$ is the vector space and *W* is a proper subspace of $ \Bbb C^3$.

As a consequence of this we get

$$dim \Bbb C^3>dim W$$
$$3>dim W$$

So it can almost have two ordered basis $\beta_1,\beta_2$ . Now these will be the column space of the matrix ***P***.

Take $\beta _1=(1,0,i)$  and $\beta_2=(1+i,1,-1)$  as the basis of ***W***.

Now the matrix **P** is $3×2$ and thus not an inveritable one.

As the theorem states:

`..P is a inveritable matrix..Then we can change the coordinate system..`

But now in this case we are getting a non inveritable matrix.

Then how can I change the basis?

(Sorry if I asked something wrong. I was new to this one. So I might have made any mistake. Kindly please mention that either. Thanks!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing basis on a space, you need two bases **on that one space**. For instance, say $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ and $\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n\}$ are two bases for $W$. Then you can create a change of basis matrix between these two bases by expressing each of the $\alpha_i$ as a linear combination of the $\beta_i$, and then use those coefficients as the columns of the matrix. For instance, if
$$
\alpha_1=b_1\beta_1+b_2\beta_2+\cdots+b_n\beta_n
$$
then $[b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n]^T$ is the first column in the change of basis matrix. Specifically, it is the change of basis matrix that takes the coordinates of a vector as expressed in the $\alpha$ basis and yields the coordinates that the same vector has in the $\beta$ basis. This always gives you an $n\times n$ invertible matrix.

None of this really cares about $V$. The fact that a larger vector space exists outside $W$ is basically irrelevant here.

However, given a basis on each of $V$ and $W$, you can do something very similar in order to construct a matrix that takes the coordinates of a vector in $W$ and yields the coordinates of the same vector now considered to be an element of $V$. But this is clearly not invertible as many vectors of $V$ do not lie in $W$. This seems to be what you have attempted.